# Is it possible to automatically coerce parameters passed to delegated methods (from the Array trait) using Moose/MooseX::Declare for Perl?

Tags: perl, moose, traits, delegation

I'm creating a class which will contain a list of IP addresses, as Net::IP objects.

I've wrapped the Net::IP object as a subtype (IPAddress), and defined a coercion from a string to IPAddress.  Then I've added an attribute to the class called ip_list with the type ArrayRef[IPAddress], and delegated to the *push* method of the *Array* trait.

```
use MooseX::Declare;
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;

use Net::IP;

subtype 'IPAddress'
    => as 'Object'
    => where { $_->isa('Net::IP') };

coerce 'IPAddress'
    => from 'Str'
    => via { Net::IP->new( $_ ) };

class IPs {

    has 'ip_list' => ( traits  => ['Array'],
                       isa    => 'ArrayRef[IPAddress]',
                       is     => 'rw',
                       coerce => 1,
                       auto_deref => 1,
                       default => sub { [] },
                       handles => {
                           add_ip    => 'push'
                       }
                       );

}
```

However if I try to call the delegated method like so:

```
my $o = IPs->new();
$o->add_ip( '192.168.0.1' );
```

I get the error "Value SCALAR(0x8017e8) did not pass container type constraint 'IPAddress' at ..."

So obviously the parameter to add_ip is not being coerced.

Is it possible to do what I'm attempting, or should I just do all this manually?  I've trawled through the Moose manuals but I've not seen anything that would indicate either way, but I am probably missing something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately Moose does not chain coercions (it would be *really* complicated to parse these internally and figure out what the "right thing to do" is in an automatic fashion), so you need to define the chain yourself:

```
use Net::IP;

class_type 'Net::IP';

coerce 'Net::IP'
    => from 'Str'
    => via { Net::IP->new( $_ ) };

subtype 'ArrayRefOfIPAddresses'
    => as 'ArrayRef[Net::IP]';

coerce 'ArrayRefOfIPAddresses'
    => from 'ArrayRef[Str]'
    => via { [ map { Net::IP->new($_) } @$_ ] };

coerce 'ArrayRefOfIPAddresses'
    => from 'Str'
    => via { [ Net::IP->new($_) ] };

coerce 'ArrayRefOfIPAddresses'
    => from 'Net::IP'
    => via { [ $_ ] };

class IPs {

    has 'ip_list' => ( traits  => ['Array'],
                       isa    => 'ArrayRefOfIPAddresses',
                       # ... rest of declaration as before
                     );

}
```

PS. since you are using the Array native delegation trait, I would recommend you avoid `auto_deref` - add a handler instead:

```
has ip_list => (
    is => 'bare',
    # ...
    handles => {
        # ...
        ip_list => 'elements',
    },
);
```

Comment: Hrrrm, that doesn't seem to be working the way I'd expect.  If I use Data::Dumper to inspect the resulting object, ip_list is a shown as an array of strings.  So it isn't doing the coercion _or_ the typechecking :/

Comment: @Paul: I'll take a look in ~2 hours to see what happened.. :(

Comment: Thanks, I'll double check that I didn't do something silly.  I'd have done so today but I've been up to my eyeballs at work.

Comment: @Paul: update: here's where I'm at so far: http://paste.scsys.co.uk/53787 .. this might be an issue with the recent reimplementation of native attrs in Moose 1.16.  (Update2: yes it's a bug.)

Comment: Ether, thank you so much, I thought I was going mad :)  I'll take a slightly different approach for the moment, and keep an eye on things.